# Rails Search results with random geo city

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geo

I have an application with a search that gets users.  When the current_user does a search, it pulls random users from the database.  It then pulls locations within X miles of the current_user's location from the database and stores them in @locations.  When the results are displayed the users location is just a random from @locations (@locations.sample.city).

My question: What would be the best way to cache the results.  For example if the search returned User2's location at Nantucket then when the search is performed again, or the page is refreshed, User2 will still have Nantucket as it's location instead of another random location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the user_id as the cache key and then store the random location in there so when the page refresh you just return the location stored in the cache and if not a new location will be assigned. eg:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('location_#{userid}') { @locations.sample.city }
```